# Find isomorphism between groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Find out if the following pairs of groups are isomorphic:

1 $(\mathbb {Z}_{7}\setminus\{0\}; .)$ with $(\mathbb {Z}_{6}; +)$

2 $(\mathbb {R}_{+}; .)$ with $(\mathbb {R}\setminus\{0\}; .)$

3 $(\mathbb {R}\setminus\{0\}; .)$ with $(\mathbb {C}\setminus\{0\}; .)$

4 $(\mathbb {R}; +)$×$(\mathbb {R}; +)$ with $(\mathbb {C}; +)$

5 $(\mathbb {Z}_{2}; +)$×$(\mathbb {Z}_{2}; +)$ with $(\mathbb {Z}_{4}; +)$

6 the group of symmetries of the equilateral triangle with group of the all permutations of {$1,2,3$}.

I know that I have to find some bijective function which is homomorphism. But it takes very long time to confirme all possibilities. I would like to now if there is any general way how to find out if two groups are  isomorphic.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: "But it takes very long time to confirme all possibilities". On the contrary, a quick search on MSE gives all answers. Have you ever looked at the right margin?

Comment: In general, there is no mechanical algorithm to determine if two groups are isomorphic. The first step is to weed out the "impossibles", so: the orders of the two groups must match, the orders of the individual elements must match, and generators under any proposed isomorphism must map to generators. After that, it comes down to experience and cleverness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The groups from item 1 are isomorphic because they are both cyclic groups of order $6$ ($(\mathbb{Z}_7\setminus\{0\},.)$ is generated by $3$).

The groups of item 2 are not isomorphic, because $(\mathbb{R}_+,.)$ has no element of order $2$, whereas $(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\},.)$ has such an element ($-1$).

In general, examining the orders of the elements is a good strategy to prove that two groups are *not* isomorphic.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: 3). Might prove a bit of a challenge-an element of order $2$, is of course, a solution to the equation $x^2  = 1$ (which exists in both groups of problem 3) , and I suggest investigation of the equation $x^4 =1$ (some rearrangement and factorization might be helpful).